# Is it possible to obtain all TM's?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I'm afraid that throughout the course of my game I have taken some actions which may prevent me from obtaining a TM. Is it possible for this to happen, or is it always possible to acquire every TM?

Comment: Something like what? I'm not 100% sure what you're asking. Are you wondering if it's possible to permanently miss some TMs, or if all TMs are available in the game?

Comment: More this first thing @Wipqozn

Answer (score 12):

Yes, it is possible to obtain all TMs. There is no action (or inaction) that will make a TM unobtainable through the course of gameplay. Note however that not every move has a corresponding TM - some moves must be taught in other ways.

Here is a table of where all 100 TMs and 5 HMs are in X & Y

| TM | Move | Location | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **TM01** | *Hone Claws* | Route 5 |  |
| **TM02** | *Dragon Claw* | Victory Road |  |
| **TM03** | *Psyshock* | Victory Road |  |
| **TM04** | *Calm Mind* | Anistar City Gym |  |
| **TM05** | *Roar* | Battle Maison Prize | Costs 24 BP |
| **TM06** | *Toxic* | Route 14 |  |
| **TM07** | *Hail* | Shalour City PokeMart |  |
| **TM08** | *Bulk Up* | Snowbelle City |  |
| **TM09** | *Venoshock* | Route 6 |  |
| **TM10** | *Hidden Power* | Anistar City |  |
| **TM11** | *Sunny Day* | Lumiose City PokeMart |  |
| **TM12** | *Taunt* | Lysandre Labs |  |
| **TM13** | *Ice Beam* | Snowbelle City Gym |  |
| **TM14** | *Blizzard* | Anistar City PokeMart |  |
| **TM15** | *Hyper Beam* | Anistar City PokeMart |  |
| **TM16** | *Light Screen* | Kiloude City PokeMart |  |
| **TM17** | *Protect* | Parfum Palace |  |
| **TM18** | *Rain Dance* | Lumiose City PokeMart |  |
| **TM19** | *Roost* | Route 8 |  |
| **TM20** | *Safeguard* | Shalour City PokeMart |  |
| **TM21** | *Frustration* | Cyllage City |  |
| **TM22** | *Solar Beam* | Route 21 |  |
| **TM23** | *Smack Down* | Battle Maison Prize | Costs 32 BP |
| **TM24** | *Thunderbolt* | Lumiose City Gym |  |
| **TM25** | *Thunder* | Anistar City PokeMart |  |
| **TM26** | *Earthquake* | Route 22 |  |
| **TM27** | *Return* | Route 4 |  |
| **TM28** | *Dig* | Shalour City PokeMart |  |
| **TM29** | *Psychic* | Pokemon Village |  |
| **TM30** | *Shadow Ball* | Terminus Cave |  |
| **TM31** | *Brick Break* | Terminus Cave |  |
| **TM32** | *Double Team* | Anistar City Pokemon Centre | Talk to the witch at 9AM |
| **TM33** | *Reflect* | Kiloude City PokeMart |  |
| **TM34** | *Sludge Wave* | Battle Maison Prize | Costs 32 BP |
| **TM35** | *Flamethrower* | Anistar City Pokemon Center |  |
| **TM36** | *Sludge Bomb* | Route 19 |  |
| **TM37** | *Sandstorm* | Shalour City PokeMart |  |
| **TM38** | *Fire Blast* | Anistar City PokeMart |  |
| **TM39** | *Rock Tomb* | Cyliage City Gym |  |
| **TM40** | *Aerial Ace* | Connecting Cave |  |
| **TM41** | *Torment* | Laverre City |  |
| **TM42** | *Facade* | Dendimelle Town |  |
| **TM43** | *Flame Charge* | Kalos Power Plant |  |
| **TM44** | *Rest* | Cyliage City |  |
| **TM45** | *Attract* | Route 12 |  |
| **TM46** | *Thief* | Camphier Town |  |
| **TM47** | *Low Sweep* | Tower of Mastery |  |
| **TM48** | *Round* | Battle Maison Prize | Costs 16 BP |
| **TM49** | *Echoed Voice* | Lumiose City – Hotel Richisseme |  |
| **TM50** | *Overheat* | Kiloude City PokeMart |  |
| **TM51** | *Steel Wing* | Battle Maison Prize | Costs 32 BP |
| **TM52** | *Focus Blast* | Anistar City PokeMart |  |
| **TM53** | *Energy Ball* | Route 20 |  |
| **TM54** | *False Swipe* | Lumiose City |  |
| **TM55** | *Scald* | Couriway Town |  |
| **TM56** | *Fling* | Lost Hotel |  |
| **TM57** | *Charge Beam* | Route 13 |  |
| **TM58** | *Sky Drop* | Kiloude City |  |
| **TM59** | *Incinerate* | Battle Maison Prize | Costs 16 BP |
| **TM60** | *Quash* | Battle Maison Prize | Costs 24 BP |
| **TM61** | *Will-O-Wisp* | Route 14 |  |
| **TM65** | *Acrobatics* | Courmaline City |  |
| **TM63** | *Embargo* | Courmaline City |  |
| **TM64** | *Explosion* | Battle Maison Prize | Costs 48 BP |
| **TM65** | *Shadow Claw* | Glittering Cave |  |
| **TM66** | *Payback* | Geosenge Town |  |
| **TM67** | *Retaliate* | Battle Maison Prize | Costs 48 BP |
| **TM68** | *Giga Impact* | Kiloude City PokeMart |  |
| **TM69** | *Rock Polish* | Route 11 |  |
| **TM70** | *Flash* | Reflection Cave |  |
| **TM71** | *Stone Edge* | Frost Cavern |  |
| **TM72** | *Volt Switch* | Battle Maison Prize | Costs 48 BP |
| **TM73** | *Thunder Wave* | Route 10 |  |
| **TM74** | *Gyro Ball* | Reflection Cave |  |
| **TM75** | *Swords Dance* | Lumiose City PokeMart |  |
| **TM76** | *Struggle Bug* | Lumiose City PokeMart |  |
| **TM77** | *Psych Up* | Anistar City PokeMart | Talk to the witch at 7PM |
| **TM78** | *Bulldoze* | Lumiose City PokeMart |  |
| **TM79** | *Frost Breath* | Frost Cavern |  |
| **TM80** | *Rock Slide* | Couriway Town |  |
| **TM81** | *X-Scissor* | Azure Bay |  |
| **TM82** | *Dragon Tail* | Lumiose City Museum |  |
| **TM83** | *Infestation* | Santalune City Gym |  |
| **TM84** | *Poison Jab* | Shalour City PokeMart |  |
| **TM85** | *Dream Eater* | Battle Maison Prize | Costs 48 BP |
| **TM86** | *Grass Knot* | Courmaline City Gym |  |
| **TM87** | *Swagger* | Battle Maison Prize | Costs 24 BP |
| **TM88** | *Sleep Talk* | Cyliage City (Cyliage Hotel) |  |
| **TM89** | *U-turn* | Couriway Town |  |
| **TM90** | *Substitute* | Anistar City Pokemon Center |  |
| **TM91** | *Flash Cannon* | Kiloude City |  |
| **TM92** | *Trick Room* | Courmaline City |  |
| **TM93** | *Wild Charge* | Kiloude City PokeMart |  |
| **TM94** | *Rock Smash* | Ambrette Town |  |
| **TM95** | *Snarl* | Lost Hotel |  |
| **TM96** | *Nature Power* | Ambrette Town Hotel |  |
| **TM97** | *Dark Pulse* | Route 15 | Access via Route 16 (Cut through some bushes then surf up the river). |
| **TM98** | *Power-Up Punch* | Shalour City Gym |  |
| **TM99** | *Dazzling Gleam* | Laverre City Gym |  |
| **TM100** | *Confide* | Courmaline City |  |
|  |  |  |  |
| **HM01** | *Cut* | Parfum Palace | Inside the maze |
| **HM02** | *Fly* | Courmaline City | Given by Prof Sycamore |
| **HM03** | *Surf* | Shalour City | Given by Calem/Serena |
| **HM04** | *Strength* | Cyllage City | Given by Grant |
| **HM05** | *Waterfall* | Route 19 | Given by Shauna |

#### References:

- [Nowgamer](http://www.nowgamer.com/cheats/pokemonxycheatsandguides/2122654/pokemon_x_y_guide_all_tm_hm_locations.html)

Comment: Thanks. I will try to check it all because if I recall correctly with one talk I entered "No" and didn't obtain TM. When I want to talk again there wasn't such Yes/No option. After positive check I will accept your answer :)

Comment: @iber - There are some situations where you need to answer a question to get the TM, although if you get the question wrong you can always try again the next day.